# Page error on page refresh Ember app

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, routes, page-refresh

I have an ember app that I am developing and everything is working fine except when I refresh the page whilst on a nested route eg. `/projects/1` I receive the following error:

`Assertion Failed: You may not pass`undefined`as id to the store's find method`

I am fairly sure this is to do with the way I have setup my routing but can't seem to reorganise them to fix it.

They look like so:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto',
  rootURL: '/'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('projects', { path: '/'});
  this.route('project', { path: '/projects/:id' });
});
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion for you would be to change `:id` segment do `:project_id` - [it's how they define it in documentation.](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) So your router code looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('projects', { path: '/'});
  this.route('project', { path: '/projects/:project_id' });
});
```

If this doesn't help, create:

```
App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('project', params.project_id);
  },
});
```

If you still get error with passing `undefined` to `store.find` try to `console.log(params)` and see if `project_id` is defined there and matches value from URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel your first suggestion using project_id has helped to fix this! :)